# Alfresco REST, file upload: cannot set description and filename

Tags: java, rest, http, alfresco

I'm using the following code to upload a file onto Alfresco

```
CloseableHttpClient client=HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost(AlfrescoRequests.getUploadRequest()+"?alf_ticket="+DocumentUno.alFrescoSessionTicket.replace("\"", ""));
    System.out.println(AlfrescoRequests.getUploadRequest()+"?ticket="+DocumentUno.alFrescoSessionTicket.replace("\"", ""));
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.RFC6532);

    reqEntity.addPart("filedata", new FileBody(file));

    reqEntity.addPart("alt_destination",new StringBody("workspace://SpacesStore/9a37fce5-2715-4730-a245-64f161304879"));
    reqEntity.addPart("filename",new StringBody("ip_VM1985.txt"));

    reqEntity.addPart("description", new StringBody("Descrizione del file"));

    postMethod.setEntity(reqEntity);

    System.out.println("executing request " + postMethod.getRequestLine());
    CloseableHttpResponse resp = client.execute(postMethod);
```

Where AlfrescoRequests.getUploadRequest() gives the REST request URL (query-part excluded)

```
public static String getUploadRequest()
{
    return DocumentUno.ECM_ADDRESS+"/alfresco/service/api/upload";
}
```

The upload is done correctly, i get a code 200, but the description is not set and i cannot specify a filename, that remains the same of the original file. Please tell me if you need other details.

Comment: Can you clarify what AlfrescoRequests.getUploadRequest() refers to? What is the webscript url?

Answer (score 1):

The `/alfresco/service/api/upload` webscript unfortunately does not handle metadata. This is a known feature of Alfresco. The filename is handled but the description, which really is the cm:description property, like any other additional standard or custom properties that you might have, are not saved.

I believe the `description` parameter of the webscript is used as the first parameter for this API:

```
ScriptNode checkin(String history, boolean majorVersion)
```

... and has nothing to do with the document title/description.

There is an open-source plugin (which I authored) that overcomes this limitation by allowing to specify any additional metadata during the upload:
http://softwareloop.com/uploader-plus-an-alfresco-uploader-that-prompts-for-metadata/

It comprises a repo amp and a share amp. Since you're using web services, you just need the repo amp.

Comment: Do you know why the filename i pass is ignored?

Comment: If the filename is taken from the original file (a plain text I understand), it's certainly provided by the client. Maybe "new FileBody(file)" is passing the filename along the content data.